# Error NullPointException

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, syntax-error

Error writing my sentence:

```
public List findWithName(String name) { 
return em.createQuery( "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName") .setParameter("custName", name) 
.setMaxResults(10) 
.getResultList(); 
}
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` error

Answer (score 0):

em is null?
try:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(...);
query.setParameter(..);
query.setMaxResult(10);
return query.getResultList();
```

EDIT: And YES, use debugger.